# Minikube Start panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x10 pc=0x8812cf]

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

My setup:

Win 10 home host, Virtualbox, Minikube.exe, Kubectl.exe, Docker Toolbox

which also create "default" VM in Virtualbox.

I need this setup for learning. I wanna do [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-a-minikube-cluster)

I have installed the Docker Toolbox which created "default" VM in Virtualbox & it's working properly.

I have used

```
 minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.4.0" --vm-driver="virtualbox" --show-libmachine-logs --alsologtostderr
```

From [here](https://quip.com/1TYDAdJowAgJ)

& I am getting this :

> missing apiserver.crt in the minikube VM.

I do not have the localkube folder too.

I cannot manage to work together the ==>

```
Docker Toolbox + Minikube + Kubectl
```

under Win 10 Home with Virtualbox.

Comment: do you have the full log or traceback? https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
C:\Users\Kolly>minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.7.5" --vm-driver="virtualbox" --alsologtostderr --v=7

C:\Users\Kolly>minikube start --alsologtostderr --v=7
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
I1003 21:34:44.154518    4796 cluster.go:71] Machine exists!
Migrating to config v0
Migrating to config v1
Migrating to config v2
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x10 pc=0x8812cf]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x17498e0, 0xc042004090)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1af
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/host.MigrateHostV2ToHostV3(0xc04200a400, 0xc042458000, 0x1f, 0x21f, 0x18fc74d, 0x1, 0x0)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/host/migrate_v2_v3.go:26 +0x15f
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/host.MigrateHost(0xc0420f2000, 0xc042458000, 0x1f, 0x21f, 0x21f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x21)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/host/migrate.go:109 +0x950
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/persist.Filestore.loadConfig(0xc042414300, 0x18, 0xc04236d460, 0x1e, 0xc04236d460, 0x1e, 0xc0420f2000, 0x21, 0x1902a95)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/persist/filestore.go:122 +0x15f
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/persist.Filestore.Load(0xc042414300, 0x18, 0xc04236d460, 0x1e, 0xc04236d460, 0x1e, 0x1902a95, 0x8, 0xc0425310a0, 0x526444, ...)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine/persist/filestore.go:158 +0x21e
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.(*LocalClient).Load(0xc0420f6880, 0x1902a95, 0x8, 0x16b0b80, 0xc0422de260, 0x0)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine/client.go:142 +0x6b
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/cluster.StartHost(0x3b8d2a0, 0xc0420f6880, 0xc04239ed40, 0x40, 0x800, 0x2, 0x4e20, 0xc0422fca10, 0xa, 0x1900e4e, ...)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/cluster/cluster.go:72 +0x163
k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd.runStart.func1(0x0, 0x3bef460)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd/start.go:125 +0x83
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/util.RetryAfter(0x5, 0xc0421b24e0, 0x77359400, 0xf, 0x0)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/util/utils.go:88 +0x6b
k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd.runStart(0x3be1860, 0xc042395ee0, 0x0, 0x2)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd/start.go:131 +0x76e
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x3be1860, 0xc042395d60, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3be1860, 0xc042395d60)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:603 +0x440
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x3be0dc0, 0x3c0ec00, 0xc0425cdeb8, 0x47ed13)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 +0x36e
k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x3be0dc0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 +0x32
k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd.Execute()
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd/root.go:111 +0x34
main.main()
        /var/lib/jenkins/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/_gopath/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/main.go:38 +0x79
```